# JPA: Could not determine recommended JdbcType for <SomeCustomClass>

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I've written this `@Entity` in Java 17 using Spring Boot 3 to store information about quotes in a corresponding MySQL table.

```java
package ch.pcngroup.gestionale.entity;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.Currency;
import java.util.List;

import ch.pcngroup.gestionale.financial.Item;
import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.ElementCollection;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.JoinColumn;
import jakarta.persistence.OneToOne;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import lombok.AccessLevel;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.experimental.FieldDefaults;

@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@FieldDefaults(makeFinal = false, level = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
@Getter
@NotNull
public class Quote {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    Long id;
    
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(referencedColumnName="id")
    PrivateCustomer customer;
    
    Currency currency;
    @Column(columnDefinition="JSON")
    List<Item> items;
}
```

Now, the `items` attribute is of type `List<Item>`, where `Item` is another class that I've written. `Item` should not be an `@Entity`, because I don't want a separate table for `Item`s. The only thing I want to do with `Item`s, is to store a list of them in JSON format in the `items` field of the `quotes` table / Object.

Here is `Item.java`:

```java
package ch.pcngroup.gestionale.financial;

import java.math.BigDecimal;

import lombok.Value;

@Value
public class Item {

    String name;
    String supplierName;
    int quantity;
    BigDecimal price;
    
}
```

The problem is, that when I run the application I get following exception:
`org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.spi.JdbcTypeRecommendationException: Could not determine recommended JdbcType for ch.pcngroup.gestionale.financial.Item`.

I can't seem to find documentation or a similar case online.

May one of you know how can I solve this?

Thank you.

I tried some annotation like `@Column(columnDefinition="JSON")` but it didn't help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The current solution for that is actually to use `@JdbcTypeCode(SqlTypes.JSON)`.

For example:

```
@Entity
public class Quote {
    
    ...

    @JdbcTypeCode(SqlTypes.JSON)
    @Column(columnDefinition="JSON")
    List<Item> items;

    ...
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work for text columns.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue.
In my entity class @Entity annotation was coming from jakarta... package
I was using spring 3.xyz version

Solution: I changed the spring version to 2.7.14.
Now, @Entity annotations started coming from javax.. package

Answer (score -1):

Use @Type(type = "jsonb")

From the error we can understand that hibernate is not able to determine the type for class Item.
@Column(columnDefinition="JSON") is not enough for determining the type.
We will also have to use Type annotation from package org.hibernate.annotations

```
@Type(type = "jsonb")
```

Comment: Question is about spring boot 3, which uses hibernate 6. `@Type(type = "jsonb")` does not work for hibernate 6.

Answer (score -1):

**For those using Hibernate 6 (as me)**

Aquib Jaweb's answer gave me a good hint, but it is not supported from Hibernate 6 onwards, as the `@Type` annotation was changed.

This is what I needed to do:

1. Install these two dependencies:

```xml
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.vladmihalcea</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-types-60</artifactId>
            <version>2.15.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.hypersistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hypersistence-utils-hibernate-60</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

2. Annotate the `List<Item> items` in my `Quote.java` field with:

```java
    @Column(columnDefinition="JSON")
    @Type(JsonType.class)
```

Comment: This is completely unnecessary. Hibernate 6 comes with native JSON support. Just add `@JdbcTypeCode(SqlTypes.JSON)` on the field.

Comment: As said before 100% unnecessary! Just use @JdbcTypeCode(SqlTypes.JSON)